# Unconfirmed in the blockchain

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I was sent a bitcoin transaction 18 hours ago  and it has still yet to be confirmed.  Any idea on what I can do or when it will go through?

https://blockchain.info/tx/da635a68d9db0448b1c10feee07a91cd6901f904d609b2f0a63b202e38d641f2?show_adv=true

Answer (score 0):

Your transaction's fee was pretty low compared to the transactions that are currently happening on the network.

Your transaction was big with 2580 bytes, and that makes your fee work out to be only 22.3 satoshi per byte. [Currently, transactions are confirming in the next block that are paying about 60 satoshi per byte.](https://bitcoinfees.21.co/)

There are about 35k transactions ahead of yours in line. (But new ones join the line, so it's going to be a while.) You might want to resend the transaction with a higher fee, if you know how to do that.

Otherwise check out [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9046/5406)